# Android - buttons inside listview elements

Tags: android, android-listview, human-computer-interface

I intend to use button inside listview items, however I have not see much apps doing so and sdk also does not provide any straightforward way to do so, I am assuming that it conflicts some of the HCI guidlines or there must be some reason for this, are there any specific points because of which this is not implemented such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see any issue using buttons inside a ListView. For example you can use toggle buttons for settings activity.. As mentioned in the Joost's answer you have to use an Adapter and a layout for implementing this.. You can some other related answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482575/list-view-with-button) and [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567268/how-to-add-button-in-list-view) You may refer [this article](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html) as well..

Comment: I mean for small lists it is fine(preferences and stuff), but for dynamic list(data populated from web service etc.,) I rarely see an implementation where there are interactive elements inside list items, I what usually happens is when you click on an item a dialog or a drawer is shown but there are usually no interactive elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create your own ListAdapter and XML for the layout of the list items. This tutorial explains how to create your own ListAdapter and XML: [Custom ListView items and adapters](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/). Inside the ListAdapter you should add the code to control the button.